# Primefaces: autocomplete in hidden element not initialized

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I'm wondering if there is some way to make autocomplete working when autocomplete field is inside hidden container. It looks like suggestion box is not initialized correctly. I mean request to Bean is send and received but no data displayed as suggestion.

```
<div style="display: none;" class="citySuggestion">
    <p:autoComplete completeMethod=#{backBean.checkCity} />
</div>
```

And this container is displayed after user clicks special button. When I remove **display: none;** from container style everything works fine. I've tried to initialize this autocomplete by myself but it didn't worked:

```
jQuery('.citySuggestion').autocomplete();
jQuery('.citySuggestion').autocomplete('enable');
```

Comment: What functional requirement exactly are you trying to implement? This all doesn't make sense.

Comment: For example X step form, where each step is placed on different tab: http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples

Answer (score 0):

Well if your requirement is to render `p:autoComplete` dynamically then,
Use `h:panelGroup` with `rendered` attribute and use `layout="block"` then `h:panelGroup` will be rendered as a `DIV`.

`p:autoComplete` requires some javascript/jquery listeners bound by Primfaces when component is rendered, if you enable/disable the component from JQuery how will primefaces know when to bind those necessary listeners.